# Warum wird hier "an" benutzt statt "in"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Durch die kollektive Flucht aus dem regulären Geldsystem steigen jedoch die Preise für Sachwerte. Dadurch können spekulative Blasen **an** den Sachgütermärkten wie Gold, Aktien oder Immobilien entstehen, deren Platzen das Finanzsystem noch weiter destabilisieren kann.

Warum wird hier "an" benutzt statt "in"?

Comment: Man sagt auch "an der Börse". Siehe z.B. hier in der Bedeutungsübersicht: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Boersenkurs

Comment: danke Schön @infinitezero

Comment: Reine Spekulation, daher nur als Kommentar: Vielleicht, weil sich der Autor Blasen (vor allem solche schädlicher Natur) als etwas vorstellt, was sich auf der Oberfläche von etwas, also **an** diesem etwas, bildet, statt in seinem Inneren?

Comment: Diese Art von Präpositionalgebrauch ist ideosynkratisch und nie ganz durch Logik zu erklären. Deutsche Vögel sitzen *auf* Bäumen und englische *in* Bäumen, aber ich glaube nicht, dass das an tiefer liegenden grundsätzlich unterschiedlichen mentalen Modellen von Tieren und Pflanzen liegt.

Comment: @KilianFoth bedeutet "idiosynkratisch" in deiner Kommentare =sehr überempfindlich ?

Comment: @user26646 Nein, es heisst nur "vom jeweiligen Verb abhängig und nicht vorhersagbar".

Comment: @KilianFoth Danke Schön Bruder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich kann keine Quelle angeben, aber für mich richtet sich die Präposition danach, was mit dem Begriff *Markt* gemeint ist.

- ***Im** Markt* bezeichnet eine konkrete Verkaufseinrichtung in Form eines Gebäudes, **in dem** etwas stattfindet. Beispiele: Supermarkt, Markthalle
- ***Auf** dem Markt* bezeichnet einen Marktplatz, **auf** dem etwas stattfindet.
- ***Am** Markt* meint den abstrakten Begriff *Markt*, der ein Absatzgebiet oder die Gesamtheit der Vorgänge des Kaufs und Verkaufs bezeichnet. Beispiele: Goldmarkt, Aktienmarkt, Immobilienmarkt

Comment: aber wie kann man unterscheiden zwischen auf/im Markt, die beide Bedeutung sind sehr ähnlich

Comment: @user26646 Das habe ich doch geschrieben: **im** Supermarkt → **im** Markt; **auf** dem Marktplatz → **auf** dem Markt. Ich wüsste nicht, wie ich es noch deutlicher schreiben sollte.